# Viewing a binary file in mysql on my LAMP command line server scrambles my characters

Tags: mysql, character, lamp

Alright, I'm lost on this one.

I have a sql database on a LAMP server.  On that server is a single database called `frame` and a single table called `frame_info` with three columns, `frame_data`(a BLOB), `frame_name`(varchar), and `surgeon_name`(varchar).  I am adding the binary data through a rather convoluted path, so I wanted to look at the binary data to make sure it arrived intact (I know visually inspecting binary data can be very misleading, I just wanted to take a look).  When I get on to look at my BLOB, I do:

```
mysql> use frame;
mysql> select frame_name from frame_info;
```

=========

frame_name

=========

frame 1

=========

(**looks good**)

```
mysql>select frame_data from frame_info;
```

the screen displays a bunch of binary data, then should say `mysql> _`.  Instead, all of my characters have been scrambled.  This is what selecting the frame_name looks like now: [image: attacked]

This is the case for my entire machine.  If I use `quit` to get out of mysql, the rest of my `LAMP` server uses the same character setup.

How does viewing a file change my entire character profile? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably running into an issue whereby the binary data has a sequence that your terminal has interpreted as an [ANSI terminal code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), which your terminal does its best to obey.

After you exit mysql, try the `reset` command to restore your terminal.

You'll probably have more luck using something like [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) when viewing binary data.